# Power Query - Filter column in Julian Format by Today

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have a table that contains the Date in the JDE Julian Date format:
CYYDDD.
For instance:

```
01.01.2021 = 121001
```

Now I would like to filter this column by today. In the past I used this SQL Statement to filter the data:

```
DB.JDate> ( FLOOR(( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - 1900 ) / 100) 
                            || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'RRDDD') )
```

How would you do this within Power Query?

Answer (score 0):

I never expect to obtain a date need to perform a very long calculation, nevertheless I have successfully return the output using m query, accept if help :)

Here is the actual outcome:

[image]

To convert Julian date to normal date, you need to this following formula, although abit long...

```
Date.AddDays(#date((1900 +
 Number.FromText(Text.Range(Number.ToText([Julian Date]),0,1)) *100 +
  Number.FromText(Text.Range(Number.ToText([Julian Date]),1,2))),1,1),
  Number.FromText(Text.Range(Number.ToText([Julian Date]),3))-1)
```

To obtain today date for filter is very easy:

```
DateTime.LocalNow()
```